# View Jmeter logs in Jenkins console

Tags: jmeter

I have been executing Jmeter tests from Jenkins without any issues. But i couldn't see custom messages(log.info output) on Jenkins console to view the progress. Is there any workaround available to see the logs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can [amend JMeter logging configuration](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-logging) so it would write the messages which normally go to [jmeter.log file](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#logging) to the console

1. Add the following lines to [`<Appenders>`](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/appenders.html) section of the *log4j2.xml* file:

   ```
   <Console name="STDOUT" target="SYSTEM_OUT">
     <PatternLayout pattern="%d %p %c{1.}: %m%n"/>
   </Console>
   ```
2. Add the following line to `<Loggers><Root>` section:

   ```
    <AppenderRef ref="STDOUT"/>
   ```

Once done you will see the same messages as in jmeter.log file going to Jenkins console.

Comment: Thanks Dmitri for your time and efforts.. Working as expected.